# Get value from JSON tree but with a number in id ('300px')

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to get a picture link that is in my JSON tree:

[image: JSON tree]

I'm coding in javascript, and I'm trying to grab that data with:

```
data.response.cases[1].image.300px
```

But I have the error (In firefox) :

```
SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal
```

I have tried like that:

```
data.response.cases[i-1].image[0]
```

But the result is 'undefined'

Have you any idea of how to get this link ?
Thanks

Comment: use square brackets `data.response.cases[1].image["300px"]`

Answer (score -2):

First, "cases" is an object, not an array.
Second, the property "300px" starts with a number, therefore it has the be accessed using the following syntax:

```
data.response.cases['0'].image['300px'];
```